# Requirement to deploy Java web service

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-axis, soa

My web application is built on servlet and JSP deployed on JBoss 4 EAP server and Apache2 as web server.

I have to build a java based web service. 
My question is,  do i need anything else in terms hardware, software or middle ware to deploy web service for production except the JBoss and apache ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need anything else in terms of middleware to create a web service as you already have an application server (JBOSS) into which you can deploy your application, and I assume you are fronting it with Apache for security or to act as the SSL engine for your app.

For developing the web services themselves you will need skills in one of the available libraries that can help you with this (e.g. Apache CXF, Jersey or Spring Web Services).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  I am in planning state of implementing the  web service. what should be the criteria to choose over the SOAP and RESTful services ?